# Paragraph field in view relationship

Tags: views, 9, paragraphs

Created a paragraph type with field named "related literature paragraph" as entity reference and inserted this paragraph type to a content type called landing page for a field named  body details. Then created views but i am unable to relate the field "related literature paragraph" . I could not able to see paragraph referenced field name or Content referenced field name in relationship.

I could see only Paragraph using field_related_literature_paragraph .

But i could not able to relate the content please help

Note : Body details field is an entity reference revision type